# Import *.dacpac into SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql, visual-studio, import, dacpac

I've create a SQL Server Database project in VisualStudio 2012.

Is there a way to import a *.dacpac file from the **command line** into a project? Database project have to be updated to the current state of the database.

I known that there is a command available in the context menu in the VS2012 but I need to do it from command line to be able to automate this process.

Import of SQL file instead of *.dacpac file would be also accepted.

Comment: I got answer from microsoft person - it isn't possible in the current version of SSDT

Answer (score 1):

As far as I known that isn't possible. There is a plan to put such funcionaliny in the next releases of SSTD.